# Returning structs with string values in C

Tags: c, esp32

I'm writing a function that will return a struct with two string variables, SSID and password. The functions purpose is to generate an SSID based on mac address data which gets called from a hardware api that updates a pointer to a variable.

The function creates and returns the custom type. When I set one of the string variables manually with quotes, the calling function receives the data fine. However when I set the variable to the value of another variable, it doesn't. What's missing here?

```c
typedef struct {
    char *ssid;
    char *password;
} wifi_auth_t;

typedef wifi_auth_t *wifi_auth;

void getmac( uint8_t *mac ) {
  mac[0] = 0xFF;
  mac[1] = 0xFF;
  mac[2] = 0xFF;
  mac[3] = 0xFF;
  mac[4] = 0xFF;
  mac[5] = 0xEE;
}

wifi_auth_t* wifi_set_ap_details() {
  uint8_t mac[6];
  wifi_auth_t *wifi;
  wifi = (wifi_auth_t *)malloc(sizeof(wifi_auth_t));
  getmac(mac);

  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
    printf("0x%.2X ", mac[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  char ssid[20];
  sprintf(ssid, "WifiDevice_%X%X%X", mac[3], mac[4], mac[5]);

  wifi->ssid = ssid;

  printf("%s\n", wifi->ssid);
  wifi->password = "stackoverflow";
  return wifi;
  free(wifi);
}


int main() {
  wifi_auth_t *wifi = wifi_set_ap_details();
  printf("Wifi: %s\n", wifi->ssid);
  printf("Pass: %s\n", wifi->password);

}
```

Comment: `return wifi;` then `free(wifi);` isn't going to work.  And `char ssid[20];` ceases to exist when the function returns.

Comment: Removing free(wifi) doesn't seem to fix the issue, I want `char ssid[20]` to be cleared hence attributing it to the wifi struct

Comment: Your `wifi_auth` holds two pointers only. Either you need this struct to have `ssid[20]` or have another malloc call for ssid in that struct. :)

Comment: see how SDK API functions return values in structs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're not familiar with C where you have to manage memory explicitly.

First, `uint8_t mac[6];` and `char ssid[20];` don't exist after the function exits, so pointers to them in the allocated wifi struct will point to possibly random stuff. One way to handle this, if you know the size will always be the same, is to specify the actual storate in the struct, as in:

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t mac[6];
    char ssid[20];
} wifi_auth_t;
```

Second, when you allocate `wifi`, you can't free it until the last place it's used, which will be somewhere in the code that calls this function `main()` in this case). When return is executed, nothing after that point is reached, so the `free()` won't ever be executed.

You'll have to change a few other bits, like how mac is set, but that should be minor.